# Dynamic Forms in react-redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

we using the library react-redux-form for creating forms: https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form

We have a table where each row in the table is also an editable form with two fields. We don't know how many rows there will be at a given time. We need to be able to edit multiple forms at the same time.

How can we dynamically add forms to the forms reducer so each form can manage its own state?

Answer (score 0):

Use [FieldArray](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form-arrays) to achieve this. [Here is a CodeSandBox working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xvrv30p95q) as well.

[image: Example project looks like this:]